# javax validation for login(email or phone)

Tags: java, bean-validation, javax

```
class SingIn {

    private String login;

    private String password;

    public SingIn(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

Login property could be an email(pattern ".+@.+") or a phone number(pattern "\+\d+").

Is it possible somehow with javax annotation to validate the login property?

Comment: Do you mean like [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by composing 2 `@Pattern` annotations with logical `OR`:

```
@ConstraintComposition(OR)
@Pattern(regexp = ".+@.+")
@Pattern(regexp = "\+\d+")
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface EmailOrPhone {
```

See also the topic [Boolean composition of constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#example-boolean-constraint-composition) in the Hibernate Validator documentation.